# Impala/Hive expose partitioned parquet files as table

Tags: hive, impala

I have used `df.to_parquet(path="...", partition_cols="period")` to write a dataframe to parquet files on HDFS (Cloudera CDH). This works fine, a subfolder structure is created (`period=YYYYMMDD`) and when I read individual parquet files they contain the expected data (as expected they do not contain the `period` column as it was partitioned out). I am now trying to create a table using Impala/Hive.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE lab.tablename
LIKE PARQUET '/data/.../db/tablename/period=20200101/dhfjksdhdsakjdhjk.parquet'
PARTITIONED BY (period INT)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/data/.../db/tablename'
```

At first, it seems to work. The table shows up in the database, the columns are correctly listed,
the `period` key is even listed as partition key. However

```
select * from lab.tablename
>>  Done. 0 results.
```

Somehow Impala doesn't seem to set the references correctly. I also tried to:

```
COMPUTE STATS lab.tablename
>> Updated 0 partition(s) and 2 column(s).
```

and get 0 rows when checking

```
SHOW TABLE STATS lab.tablename
```

If I write the same data in a non partitioned fashion, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive isn't aware of the partitions in the metastore even though you used the correct foldering.
use:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE lab.tablename
```

And it should discover the partitions that are missing and add them to the metastore.

Impala: run this command so it picks up the changes:

```
INVALIDATE METADATA lab.tablename
```

[Good Read](https://analyticshut.com/msck-repair-fixing-partitions-in-hive-table/) if you want a more detailed explanation.

Comment: amazing! Using Hive query editor I can now run my select succesfully (after running msck repair). But in Impala I still get zero results. I cleared cache etc, but perhaps takes some time?

Comment: okay one just needs to run `INVALIDATE METADATA lab.tablename` in Impala to make it work there. Matt, can you add this in your answer to I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks for helping make this a better answer I appreciate it.